# The polynomial ring of a right duo ring is semicommutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

A ring $R$ is said to be right duo if every right ideal is two sided. A ring $R$ is said to semicommutative if $a,b\in R$ satisfy $ab=0$ then $aRb=(0)$.
I am thinking about whether the polynomial ring of a right duo ring is semicommutative.
Proof Attempt: Let $R$ be a right duo ring. Take $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ such that $f(x)g(x)=0$. We have to prove that $f(x)h(x)g(x)=0$ $\forall h(x) \in R[x]$. How to go further, should I expand $f(x),g(x)$?

Comment: Assuming your rings have $1$, rather than being rngs. Consider the right ideal $gR$, generated by $g$. We have that $g\in gR$, and since $gR$ must be also a left ideal, then $hg\in gR$. This means that there are $r_1,r_2,...,r_n\in R$ such that $hg=gr_1+gr_2+...+gr_n$. Multiply this by $f$ from the left and use that $fg=0$.

Comment: @NDB $gR$ is a right $R$ submodule of $R[x]_R$, but not a right ideal of $R$ or of $R[x]$.

Comment: @rschwieb I wrote the comment talking entirely about their $R[x]$. I just reused the $R$ without noticing.

Comment: @NDB It's not only a notational problem, it also derails your hint. You say you meant that $gR[x]$ must also be a left ideal, but that is not true: $R$ is the thing that's right duo, not $R[x]$.